# Why don't I get my postback event fired when I click on the ImageButton of my ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, postback, imagebutton

I have a `ListView` with an `ImageButton`.
I've set the `OnItemCommand` event of the `ListView`.
I've set the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` of the `ImageButton`.

For some reason the postback isn't fired when I click that `ImageButton`.

I tried to do the same with a normal `<asp:Button>` and it worked without problems. I had to set the `OnSubmitBehavior` to `false`.

So I tried setting the same to the `ImageButton` and still doesn't work.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Ive checked again and the ImageButton is doing PostBack to Page_Load instead of going to ListView_ItemCommand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the workaround rather than the solution to this specific problem but chances are this will help you:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2008/01/imagebutton-in-templatefield-does-not.html

Comment: Yes. I Actually solved it this way. Sorry for the late answer.